# variable on edit text changed listener

Tags: java, android, addtextchangedlistener

I need help with this code, it's not working. I would like to change `boolean` value to `true` when the text changed. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class Atiras {

    public void atirasfigyelo(final EditText valtozo,Cursor sql,String SQLoszlop,final boolean ell){

        valtozo.setText("" + sql.getInt(sql.getColumnIndex(SQLoszlop)));

        ell=false;
        valtozo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                ell=true;
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                valtozo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is this your full code? if not please upload your full code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to create a JavaBean or POJO instead of this argument list. Then you can change the 'ell' variable. And the Cursor object must be to close. 
First you do the query then convert the record to object. Then you make the object what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work because in your function:
 `public void atirasfigyelo(final EditText valtozo,Cursor sql,String SQLoszlop,final boolean ell){`

you are making `ell` as `final boolean ell` final variable.

You can create a class level variable that you can change from inside annonimus  class like below:

```
public class Atiras {
    private boolean isTrue;
    public void atirasfigyelo(final EditText valtozo, Cursor sql, String SQLoszlop, final boolean ell) {    
        valtozo.setText("" + sql.getInt(sql.getColumnIndex(SQLoszlop)));

        isTrue= false;
        valtozo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {    
                isTrue= true;    
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                valtozo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);    
            }    
        });    
    }    
}
```

It will work because [6.3. Scope of a Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement.

Comment: When i delete "final" ---->On Text Changed ..... --->Variable 'ell' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final :( Please help me

Comment: I must change {ell} value to True